# array sorting in Javascript based on certain key value and sort again based on another key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

An array contains the list of values as below:

```
    Object {status: "Pen"
    apptDate:"12-06-2001 04:00 PM "
    func:"OOS"}

  Object {status: "Pen"
    apptDate:"14-03-2001 04:00 PM "
    func:"OOS"}

    Object {status: "Pen"
    apptDate:"15-09-2001 04:00 PM "
    func:"OOS"}

 Object {status: "Pen"
    apptDate:"11-01-2001 04:00 PM "
    }

   Object {status: "Pen"
    apptDate:"10-02-2001 04:00 PM "
    }
```

Need to create a new array based on the current array that will have the object.func value as "OOS" should be pushed first inside the array while keeping the apptDate in asc order, incase no value present in object.func then sort the sort the array based on apptDate in asc order

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: btw, `15-18-2001` is not a valid date.

Comment: need to create a new array based on the current array that will have the object.func value as "OOS" should be pushed first inside the array with keeping the apptDate in asc order, incase no value present in object.func then sort the sort the array based on apptDate in asc order

Answer (score 2):

With an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string, you could use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), while respecting `'OOS'` sorting on top.

```js
var array = [{ status: "Pen", apptDate: "2001-06-12 04:00", func: "OOS" }, { status: "Pen", apptDate: "2001-03-14 04:00", func: "OOS" }, { status: "Pen", apptDate: "2001-09-15 04:00", func: "OOS" }, { status: "Pen", apptDate: "2001-01-11 04:00" }, { status: "Pen", apptDate: "2001-02-10 04:00" }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (b.func === 'OOS') - (a.func === 'OOS') || a.apptDate.localeCompare(b.apptDate);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You have an invalid date in input: `2001-06-12-06-2001`

Comment: @NisargShah, well spotted.

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks for the response. what if i needs to sort on adding one more condition if status value is "pen" along with func === 'OOS' can we just use  like below:    return (b.func === 'OOS' ||b.status==='Pen') - (a.func === 'OOS'||b.status==='Pen') || a.apptDate.localeCompare(b.apptDate);

Comment: @Sangeethacg, actually all object have `status: 'Pen'`. should it sorted above `func`, ath the same place, or below of it? please add an extended example with more all the properties you want to sort. the properties should be different to demonstate the sorting result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a comparing function such as this:

```
function(a,b){
    if(a.func && a.func == "OOS" && a.func != b.func){
    return -1;
  } else {
    return new Date(a.apptDate) - new Date(b.apptDate);
  }
}
```

Note: I've updated some dates to make them valid.

```js
var arr = [{
  status: "Pen",
  apptDate: "12-18-2001 04:00 PM ",
  func: "OOS"
}, {
  status: "Pen",
  apptDate: "9-18-2001 04:00 PM ",
  func: "OOS"
}, {
  status: "Pen",
  apptDate: "11-18-2001 04:00 PM ",
  func: "OOS"
}, {
  status: "Pen",
  apptDate: "11-18-2001 04:00 PM "
}, {
  status: "Pen",
  apptDate: "10-18-2001 04:00 PM "
}];

arr.sort(function(a,b){
 if(a.func && a.func == "OOS" && a.func != b.func){
   return -1;
  } else {
   return new Date(a.apptDate) - new Date(b.apptDate);
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```